# Solve $\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}$

Tags: limits

I'm a student of calculus and I am trying to get a grip of questions on old exams. The Questions i my exam will not be the same but the intuition will. This is a question about limits, where I'll have to show that my solution is correct.

Intuitively this evaluates to infinity, but I don't know how to show that it does.

$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}$

Any tips as how to go about solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can guarantee that for any positive $x$, 
$$
\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}} \geq \sqrt{x + 0} = \sqrt{x}
$$
So, it suffices to show that $\sqrt{x} \to \infty$.

Comment: I now see the light again.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}>\sqrt x\quad\text{if}\enspace x>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an **unconventional but correct answer:** 
We can actually just plug in
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\infty + \sqrt{\infty + \sqrt{\infty}}}
&= \sqrt{\infty + \sqrt{\infty + \infty}} \\
&= \sqrt{\infty + \sqrt{\infty}} \\
&= \sqrt{\infty + \infty} \\
&= \sqrt{\infty} \\
&= \infty,
\end{align*}
therefore the limit is $\infty$.

**Explanation:**

$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $\infty$ if we define $\sqrt{\infty} = \infty$.
Likewise, $g(x) = x$ is continuous at $\infty$ and $h(x,y) = x + y$ is continuous at $(\infty, \infty)$. So we have a composition of continuous functions (with each domain an appropriate subset of the extended real numbers), and thus the limit as $x \to \infty$ equals the value of the function at $\infty$.

Comment: You might point out the likelihood of the OP being deducted points from his homework (if this is homework) if he were to write this.

Comment: @Thomas I did say it was unconventional :) But I would hate a professor who deducted points for this. It's mathematically correct.

Comment: Well, as a teacher I would probably do this. When you take a class, the homework and solutions to problems usually should follow what is done in class. For example, in Calculus we usually do not extend the real line to include infinity. And as such saying $\sqrt{\infty}$ would be *wrong* simply because we haven't defined it.

Comment: It's correct, *if we define* $\sqrt{\infty} = \infty$.  Part of being correct is being scrupulous about definitions.

Comment: @Thomas You don't even have to define $\sqrt{\infty}$ for the argument to go through. You can define $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ for finite positive $x$, and $f(\infty) = \infty$.

Comment: @6005: Again, I just wanted to point out that in a standard calculus class writing things like $\sqrt{\infty}$ will loose you points. It is the same discussion that always comes up with whether or not $\frac{dy}{dy}$ is a fraction. Context is everything.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure, I agree.

Comment: @Thomas It's not really on the same level. It depends on if your calculus course develops $\infty$ as a special case, or as an element of the extended real numbers. On the other hand making $\frac{dy}{dx}$ a fraction requires a *lot* more work. Anyway there's no point in continuing this argument.

Comment: @6005: Sure, let's leave it at that. I just wanted to OP to know about it so that he doesn't turn in your solution (if this is homework).

Comment: Sweet. It's from last years finals in a calculus course.